# How to check if a relationship already exists?

Tags: c#, duplicates, dynamics-crm-2011, relationships

In my CRM, I have an "Advisor" entity that is related to the "Contact" entity with N:N relationship. After creating the Advisor entity I associate the Advisor to the Contact with the following code:

```
_service.Associate("contact", contactid, relationship, relatedAdvisors);
```

`relatedAdvisors` is an entity reference collection. However, if the relationship already exists, I get the error,

> "Cannot insert duplicate Key"

How can I check if this advisor is already related to the contact?

Answer (score 2):

Following query should work for you. However I have not compiled it but you can get an idea.

```
// Create new object of RelatedAdvisors
var newRelatedAdvisors = new new_RelatedAdvisors();

// Go through all the advisors in colletion
foreach(var advisor in relatedAdvisors)
{
    // Search of existing relationship between contact and advisor
    var existingAdvisor = (from a in linqContext.CreateQuery<new_RelatedAdvisors>() where a.contactid ==   contactid && a.Id == advisor.Id select a).FirstOrDefault();

    // if relationship does not exist then add add advisor to newly created collection object
    if(xyz == null || xyz.Count() == 0)
    {
        // Add advisor to newRelatedAdvisors 
    }
}
// associate the contact with newly created collection of relatedadvisors
_service.Associate("contact", contactid, relationship, newRelatedAdvisors);
```

**Note**

I have not compiled this code because currently I don't have access to development system. But it might help you to get an idea.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand this. I assume that xyz will hold the collection of related Advisors. I believe this will not be an accurate check, what if the existing xyz contains the advisors A, B and C, while my new relatedAdvisors are D, E and F ? Aren't we here only checking whether this contact has any relationship with advisor but we're not actually checking the existing relationships ?

Comment: Hi, just edited the code. However you will need to make changes to get it working because I don't have dev setup at the moment. I like the solution presented by @Andrii Butenko as well. I believe that solution will be helpful for you because that is compiled code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm unable to use "linqContext" is this a built-in object ? Sorry I'm a CRM beginner

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention, its OrganizationServiceContext type. You can create it like `var linqContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(_service);`

Comment: `OrganizationServiceContext` is a class defined under `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client` assembly

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help:

```
private static bool RelationshipExists(IOrganizationService service, string relationshipname, Guid entity1Id, string entity1Name, Guid entity2Id, string entity2Name)
{
    string relationship1EtityName = string.Format("{0}id", entity1Name);
    string relationship2EntityName = string.Format("{0}id", entity2Name);

    //This check is added for self-referenced relationships
    if (entity1Name.Equals(entity2Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        relationship1EtityName = string.Format("{0}idone", entity1Name);
        relationship1EtityName = string.Format("{0}idtwo", entity1Name);
    }

    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(entity1Name) { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false) };

    LinkEntity link = query.AddLink(relationshipname, 
    string.Format("{0}id", entity1Name), relationship1EtityName);

    link.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(relationship1EtityName, 
    ConditionOperator.Equal, new object[] { entity1Id });

    link.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(relationship2EntityName, 
    ConditionOperator.Equal, new object[] { entity2Id });

    return service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.Count != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, provided by @Saddam Khan, here is what I came up with. This allows to exclude already associated entities from the `relatedEntities` collection and always associate / disassociate any number of entities with two requests (first check weather they already assassinated, second associates ones that are not).

```cs
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class OrganizationServiceExtension
{
    public static void AssociateIfDisassociated(this IOrganizationService service, EntityReference entity, string relationshipName, string relationshipEntityName, EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities)
    {
        List<EntityReference> unrelatedEntities = relatedEntities.Except(service.RetrieveRelated(entity, relationshipEntityName, relatedEntities)).ToList();
        if (!unrelatedEntities.Any())
        {
            return;
        }
        service.Associate(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, new Relationship(relationshipName), new EntityReferenceCollection(unrelatedEntities));
    }

    public static void DisassociateIfAssociated(this IOrganizationService service, EntityReference entity, string relationshipName, string relationshipEntityName, EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities)
    {
        List<EntityReference> realRelatedEntities = relatedEntities.Intersect(service.RetrieveRelated(entity, relationshipEntityName, relatedEntities)).ToList();
        if (!realRelatedEntities.Any())
        {
            return;
        }
        service.Disassociate(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id, new Relationship(relationshipName), new EntityReferenceCollection(realRelatedEntities));
    }

    public static EntityReferenceCollection RetrieveRelated(this IOrganizationService service, EntityReference entity, string relationshipEntityName, EntityReferenceCollection checkIfRelatedEntities)
    {
        var relatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection();
        if (checkIfRelatedEntities?.Any() != true)
        {
            return relatedEntities;
        }

        string relatedEntityLogicalName = checkIfRelatedEntities.First().LogicalName;
        string entityIdFieldName = $"{entity.LogicalName}id";
        string relatedEntityIdFieldName = $"{relatedEntityLogicalName}id";

        //This check is added for self-referenced relationships
        if (entity.LogicalName.Equals(relatedEntityLogicalName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            entityIdFieldName = $"{entity.LogicalName}idone";
            relatedEntityIdFieldName = $"{relatedEntityLogicalName}idtwo";
        }

        var relatedEntitiesQuery = new QueryExpression(relatedEntityLogicalName) 
        { 
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(relatedEntityIdFieldName),
            LinkEntities =
            {
                new LinkEntity
                {
                    LinkToEntityName = relationshipEntityName,
                    LinkFromAttributeName = $"{relatedEntityLogicalName}id",
                    LinkToAttributeName = relatedEntityIdFieldName,
                    LinkCriteria =
                    {
                        Conditions = 
                        { 
                            new ConditionExpression(entityIdFieldName, ConditionOperator.Equal, entity.Id),
                            new ConditionExpression(relatedEntityIdFieldName, ConditionOperator.In, checkIfRelatedEntities.Select(e => e.Id).ToArray())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        List<EntityReference> relatedEntitiesList = service.RetrieveMultiple(relatedEntitiesQuery).Entities
            .Select(e => e.ToEntityReference())
            .ToList();
        relatedEntities.AddRange(relatedEntitiesList);
            
        return relatedEntities;
    }
}
```

Example usage for `System User` - `Security Role` and `System User` - `Team`:

```cs
var user = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, Guid.NewGuid());
service.AssociateIfDisassociated(
    user,
    "systemuserroles_association",
    SystemUserRoles.EntityLogicalName,
    new EntityReferenceCollection { new EntityReference(Role.EntityLogicalName, Guid.NewGuid()) });
service.AssociateIfDisassociated(
    user,
    "teammembership_association",
    TeamMembership.EntityLogicalName,
    new EntityReferenceCollection { new EntityReference(Team.EntityLogicalName, Guid.NewGuid()) });
```